# Value of attr show object object

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, imagesource

I am trying to customize a plugin to fit my needs. What I'm trying to do is when I click an image from a collection of images, I get the src of the image and restore the plugin with that image. The problem I ran into was when I get the source of the image, it gives me [object object] instead of the actual source. I used $(this).attr("src") to get the image source.

So basically my code kind of looks like this:

```
    <div id="images">
      <img src="image1"/>
      <img src="image2"/>
      <img src="image3"/>
      <img src="image4"/>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#images img").on("click", function(){
    var img_src=$(this).attr("src");
    $("#id").plugin({
      image:img_src
    });
});
});
```

EDIT: I updated my code so it is more clear what I am asking.

UPDATE: Actually the code doesn't work even when I remove all the other js from it. But it works in jsfiddle

UPDATE 2: So I was looking all over the internet for a solution and it seems that the plugin i am using is overriding the attr function somehow. Is there a way to keep it from doing that? Or maybe create an instance of jQuery that is not affected by the plugin?

Comment: Can you share a link to jsfiddle.net? I want to see what `this` is.

Comment: 'this' is $("#images img").on("click", function(){

Comment: in your <img > tag, try to include a temporary attribute called 'value', so it would be like <img src='path' value='temp'>. And then try to alert $(this).value() to see wether you get the right value

Comment: that breaks my code. with .value() it says there is no such function and with .value it gives undefined

Comment: sorry, in jquery, it should be just .val()

Comment: .val() gives an empty alert without anything in it. the image has value="testvalue"

Comment: the value stuff is not needed/overhead. If your code is similar like this it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/G9hLC/

Comment: @khuderm Have you tried `jQuery.fn.prop` instead of `jQuery.fn.attr` in case of?...

Answer (score 2):

Try exploring contents of that object by outputting to console.

Use Firebug for Firefox or Chrome integrated developers console with F12.

Open up console, modify your code:

```
var img_src=$(this).attr("src");
console.log(img_src);
$("#id").plugin({
  image:img_src
});
```

And examine output.

`$("img").attr("src")` should be string.

Comment: [img, context: img, jquery: "1.9.0", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…] this is what is printed out in the console with bunch of other information which had all sorts of info about the clicked image.

Comment: @khuderm You better post whole `click()` function here, so we can see what context are your `this` inside.

Comment: logging this and the image source gives the same thing. And this is the image I clicked on. The code is too big to post it here all

Comment: it prints basically the same thing. I dont know how to show it to you

Comment: @khuderm It will take too much time to check every possible cause like this. Try to create jsfiddle.net with least possible code you can reproduce that error.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a CSS selector problem!

It won't work because `#images img` won't work as you expected!!! It should be `img#images` to refer to `img` with id `images`.

So if you have HTML like this:

```
<img id="img1" class="useImg" src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/032/8/3/papa_happy_by_ovilia1024-d5tfw0h.png" width="30px" height="30px" />
<img id="img2" class="useImg" src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/032/a/b/papa_horrified_by_ovilia1024-d5tfwdt.png" width="30px" height="30px" />
```

You should use:

```
$('img.useImg').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Run the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aM4xw/2/

Comment: But there are many images in #images. How would I get the right image source?

Comment: But the way you do it, i have to make click events for all the images

Comment: @khuderm I updated the code and you may set `class="useImg"` to those images that you want to choose.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the attr was return an object instead of the source value was that the plugin I was using overrode the attr function. I modified it to return the src as a string and not an object. Removing it solved the problem too but the plugin needed the custom one. Thanks for all of you who tried to help me and I really appreciate it.

Comment: But you do know that `"#images img"` isn't the wise thing to do, right?